# Can we call Ajax in Django Form in onchange function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

Actually there is no html code in case of Django Form. dirrectly html selectbox/textbox happening through Django Model, with help of verbose_name and help_text

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    act_des_code = models.ForeignKey('Destionation', related_name='act_des_code',db_column='act_des_code')
    act_cit_keyname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    act_discription = models.TextField(max_length=255,verbose_name='Description')

class ActivityForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        fields = ['act_des_code', 'act_cit_keyname','act_discription']
        widgets={'act_discription': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 5})}
```

act_des_code and act_cit_keyname are two selectbox.

Note: No HTML code, All thing happening through Django Form.

in front end Onchange of act_des_code(dropDown) i want to display Destionation class column value in act_cit_keyname(dropDown). Ex: Onchange of country all city should come in city dropDown.

Your valuable comment will help me alot.

Comment: I never found it before if handling at the backend. I suggest you to handle this via ajax, an example: if `act_des_code` is changed, call ajax to find all `act_cit_keyname`... you need to create a view for return json cities..

Comment: But my requirement is to do this through Django Form. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example I used back in Django 1.3, where get_schedule() is a Javascript function.  Haven't tried it lately, but the `attrs` syntax is still available in 1.10.

```
training_class = ModelChoiceField(queryset=TrainingClass.objects.filter(active_flag=True),
                                  widget=Select(attrs={'onchange':'get_schedule();'}))
```